# Opening files in insert mode

Tags: buffers, insert-mode

How do I make vim open files in insert mode? I've got the line "startinsert" in my .vimrc, and it does what it's supposed to (vim opens in insert mode), but when I open another file it opens it in command mode. I've played around with autocmd with no luck.Any ideas?

Comment: https://changelog.com/podcast/450#transcript-22

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it, your command is only read and applyied once, when vim starts.

To get the behaviour you expect, you need to apply it to each buffer you open.

This can be done with an `:h autocmd`.

For example:

```
augroup OpenEveryBufferInInsertMode
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead,BufEnter * startinsert
augroup end
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `:set insertmode` or run `vim -y` or copy/symlink/rename `vim` executable to `evim`.

Or better switch to Emacs. If you're not going to work in Normal mode then Vim is not a right choice for you.